# Selection Sort in Python not working

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I'm working on learning algorithms, started with bubble sort and now on to selection sort. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
test = [5, 3, 6, 1, 8, 7, 2, 4]

def selection_sort(items):
    for i in range(0, len(items)-1):
        minIndex = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(items)):
            if items[j] < items[minIndex]:
                minIndex = j
            if minIndex != i:
                items[i], items[minIndex] = items[minIndex], items[i]

print("Before: ", test)
selection_sort(test)
print("After: ", test)
```

The problem is that the output I get from this is: `[1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]`
When I run it again I get the correct output of: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

Any idea why it gets caught up? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are actually doing it wrongly, you are swapping the `ith` position element with `minIndex` , in every iteration, even if its not the actual `minIndex` (You are doing it inside the inner loop)

You need to do that swap outside the inner loop, so that in the inner loop you find out the index with the minimum value element and then swap `ith` and `minIndex` position elements.

Example -

```
>>> test = [5, 3, 6, 1, 8, 7, 2, 4]
>>> def selection_sort(items):
...     for i in range(0, len(items)-1):
...         minIndex = i
...         for j in range(i + 1, len(items)):
...             if items[j] < items[minIndex]:
...                 minIndex = j
...         if minIndex != i:
...             items[i], items[minIndex] = items[minIndex], items[i]
...
>>> selection_sort(test)
>>> test
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes so much sense. Much appreciated

Comment: You are welcome, also please do remember to accept answers, if you think they helped you resolve your issue, would help the community.